# Auto Close Class Quote in HTML in PHP file in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am experience strange behavior in VS Code and it is driving me crazy. I have Auto Closing Quotes set to "always".

So everywhere I type " it will auto close for me. Except if I am writing HTML markup in a PHP file, for example: `<div class="` will not auto close. But I write just " it will.

Why is auto closing quotes not being applied when I write proper HTML while using PHP language? Is this a bug? It makes no sense and makes PHP development in VS Code really annoying.

Comment: That is enough. Create a PHP language file, start writing HTML code. Then write <div class=" and it will not auto close.

Comment: I raised an issue ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189525. I'll write an answer post here if a maintainer speaks on anything useful there.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a weird bug.